# double expectation proof

Tags: probability

[image]

my question is

[image]

Why multiply f(x)?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. In order to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close you should edit your question to include the mathematics, not just a link to an image. Then explain what you do understand, and what you don't. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$ is some discrete R.V., then $E[M]$ is the sum of all the different values $M$ can take, weighted by the probabilities. So $$E[M]=\sum_m m\times P(M=m)$$Here, $m(x)$ is some continuous distribution, so the sum is replaced by an integral.